# How to design interface shared by two classes that only one property type is different?

Tags: typescript, oop

Assume I have two classes (or more). One as a database entity, one as a json constrains. Because database entity set the property as a foreign key so that property is an object. But in the json case, the property is just a string type.

```
interface A {
    title: string
    catalogue: string
}
```

The database entity class needs catalogue to be a Object because CatObj contains other information like id, name, etc.

```
class AEntity implements A {
    public title: string
    public catalogue: CatObj
}
```

The json format

```
const aJson: A = {
    title: 'hello',
    catalogue: 'programming'
}
```

The rest properties are the same.

How do I design an interface (or other way) in TypeScript to make such constraint? Is there any other way than make the catalogue type as

```
catalogue: string | CatObj
```

Because `CatObj` is only visible in database part, `A` is a global interface used both backend and frontend part. Is there a method allow to pick up some property of an interface to make a new interface in TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about generics ?
The A Interface would be

```
interface A <TCat> {
      title: string
      catalogue: TCat
}
```

Then  AEntity would become:

```
class AEntity implements A<CatObj> {
      public title: string
      public catalogue: CatObj
}
```

and the Json would be

```
const aJson: A<string> = {
    title: 'hello',
    catalogue: 'programming'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only have a limited number of foreign keys, Andrei's answer is a simple and straight forward way to go.

Another approach would be to use conditional types in Tyescript 2.8 (unreleased at the time of writing, but will be released in Match 2018, you can get it by running `npm install -g typescript@next`). You could define your interface with the foreign key fields pointing to other interfaces and then use a conditional type to transform the interface to a version that contains just strings:

```
interface Base {
    id: string // should contain something, any type maching the structure of Base will be converted to string
}

interface A extends Base{
    title: string
    prop: number
    catalogue: CatObj
    otherFk: OtherFk;
}

interface CatObj extends Base {
    title: string
}

interface OtherFk extends Base {
    title: string
}

// JsonData will convert all fields of a type derived from Base to string 
type JsonData<T> = { [P in keyof T] : T[P] extends Base ? string : T[P] }

// will be a type { title: string;prop: number;catalogue: string;otherFk: string;id: string;}
type JsonA = JsonData<A> 


class AEntity implements A {
    public id: string
    public prop: number
    public title: string
    public catalogue: CatObjEntity // field implemented by a field of an entity type
    public otherFk: OtherFk // Or a field can be implemented using the interface
}

class CatObjEntity implements CatObj {
    public id: string
    public title: string
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I would like to use this feature when it release!